# Httpclient optimization to improve performance

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am worried about my HttpClient Reuse. I have the following class this is a Xamarin forms application that communicates to a asp.net core swagger api. Im running .net 5 core its a small delay but wondering if their anything I can do to improve my handling of the httpclient?.

I am using no libarys just the standard .net 5 httpclient?

```
public class TheHockeyLabMnHttpApi
{  
  readonly HttpClient httpClient;  
  public class MyAppApiClass
  {
   public MyAppApiClass()
   {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.BaseUrl);
   }
   
   public async Task<List<Workout>> GetAllWorkouts()
   {
     List<Workout> _result = new List<Workout>();

    var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.BaseUrl + 
    Constants.ApiSegmant + Constants.GetAllWorkouts, string.Empty));
    AddAuthenicationHeader();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var byteArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Workout>>(content);
    }

    return _result.ToList();

  }
 }
}
```

For example I would call my api as such

```
public partial class AcitivtyListPage : ContentPage
{
    TheHockeyLabMnHttpApi api;
 
public AcitivtyListPage()
{
 InitializeComponent();
 api = new TheHockeyLabMnHttpApi();
}

 public async void BindGrid()
 {
    Indicator = true;
    loadingXoomPageHome.BindingContext = this;
 
    workOutGridMain.ItemsSource = await api.GetAllWorkouts();
    workOutGridMain.RefreshData();
    Indicator = false;
 }
       
}
```

Is their anything I can do to help improve this am also suffering from a few seconds delay from the phone app to the call but I think this is more to do with the fact is communicates to https rather than plain text to the api domain.

Comment: Use `IHttpClientFactory`, and `ReadAsStringAsync` however you could instead use `Text.json` with a stream, which is more performant. Other than that, you cant speed up the internet.

Comment: Side note: `response` should be in a `using`

Comment: See also https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/

Answer (score 1):

Improving performance is a sticky question

However, you can make a few optimizations that will cull some of the most common issues.

- Use `IHttpClientFactory` which has a bunch of efficiencies and solves several problems when dealing with sockets amung other niceties.

  - [Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
- Don't read the content as a bytes, then convert to string, then deserialize it. Instead `ReadAsStringAsync` or even better, deserialize directly from stream.
- Even better, use `Text.Json` instead of `Json.Net` for deserialization, and once again deserialize directly from stream

<sub>***Note** : the first suggestion is likely going to give you the most bang for the buck, if any.*</sub>

Other than that, there are lots of reasons why your requests are taking more time than expected, but if you have a munted phone, badly designed app, or slow internet, then there is not much you can do with this code.